# Android animation with OpenGL2.0 - Conceptual questions

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm learning OpenGLES20 on Android and have some questions. Hope you guys can help me out.

1. Accordinly to Android Developers website *"...OpenGL ES allows you to define drawn objects using coordinates in three-dimensional space."*. **This and only this is strictly true or they are "hiding" de "w" coordinate?** Normal space has 3 coordinates but Clip Space has 4 (x,y,z,w), right?
2. Why the `GLES20.glBindBuffer(arg0, arg1)` function is only defined for int values if my triangle is defined in a float array?
3. Even if I doesn't put the code `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  myPositionBufferObject);` my program is working. How come this work if I'm not binding my Buffer to the OpenGL target GL_ARRAY_BUFFER??

This is the code for my Triangle. It's the super reduced code only necessary to render the simplest triangle.

```
public class Triangle {

    ByteBuffer myByteBuffer;
    FloatBuffer positionBufferObject;    

    int mProgram;

    public Triangle() {

        float vertexPositions[] = { 

                 0.75f,  0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                 0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f

        };

        myByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexPositions.length * 4);
        myByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        positionBufferObject = myByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        positionBufferObject.put(vertexPositions);
        positionBufferObject.position(0);

        String vertexShaderCode =
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                "}";

        String fragmentShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

        int myVertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(myVertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(myVertexShader);

        int myFragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(myFragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(myFragmentShader);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, myVertexShader);        
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, myFragmentShader); 

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);        

    }

    public void draw() {

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, positionBufferObject);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, what is "normal space"? All position vectors in OpenGL have 4 coordinates like it or not, otherwise transformation between coordinate spaces would not work. If you pass data to a vertex attribute using only 2 coordinates, it will actually be expanded to `vec4 (x, y, 0, 1)` automatically by GLSL. This is why you should always write: `attribute vec4 vtx_pos;` even if you are only using a 2D vector, then you don't have to do pointless things like: `mvp * vec4 (vtx_pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);`...

Comment: Normals (if that is what you were referring to) can exist purely as 3D vectors because they are directional and not positional. You don't translate or scale normals (generally). You rotate them, and that's about it - this is why the "normal matrix" is only 3x3 while all other transform matrices are 4x4.